# factoring $x^n+x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring, prime-factorization

Is there a way of factoring a polynomial of the general form $$x^n+x+1$$ in the ring $\mathbb C[x]$ or $\mathbb R[x]$ or $\mathbb Z [x]$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$? (Or perhaps with certain conditions on $n$?)

Comment: From the [looks of it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^6+%2B+x+%2B+1+%3D+0), the complex roots in the $n = 6$ case may have no closed-form expression.

Comment: x^2+x+1 is a factor for $n=5,8,11,14,17,20,\dots$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What exactly makes you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to show that $x^2+x+1$ is a factor for $n\equiv2\bmod3$ (the other factor has coefficients $1,0,-1,1,0,-1,\dots$).

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me a hint how to show this? / How you found out about this?

Comment: @flawr If $\omega$ is a root of $x^2+x+1 = \frac{x^3-1}{x-1}$, when does $\omega^n + \omega + 1 = \omega^2 + \omega + 1$?

Comment: @flawr. Just write down the other factor $k(x)$. The underneath write down $xk(x)$, then $x^2k(x)$. Line them up and you should see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hints!